# Is WP SE an appropriate place to ask for plugin recommendations?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, plugins

I need some suggestions for an ecommerce plugin that will allow users to register and seller and/or buyer to sell/buy digital products. The seller will be given time to produce the digital product and deliver to the buyer. I want my site to take a percentage off the sale.

Are plugin recommendations off topic?

Comment: The tag wiki leads you straight to http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations

Answer (score 4):

Any type of recommendations are off topic here. This does not only apply here on WPSE, this also goes for the entire Stackexchange network, the only exception being the software recommendation stack.

The problem with recommendations are is that they are opinion based with no known and proven fact, also, it does lead to spam as well.

For recommendations, try wordpress.org's support forum or the Wordpress group on google plus.

Good luck with your project